# How can I search for a Regular Expression match that begins before a certain index of a string?

Tags: swift, regex, string, nsregularexpression

Let's say I have a regular expression

```
let regexString = "\\s{1,3}(---+)\\s*"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString)
```

and a string

```
let string = "Space --- the final frontier --- these are the voyages..."
```

and let's further assume that the string was *really* long and continued after the ellipses (`...`) over several thousands of characters.

Now I want to find the first match for the regular expression `regex`, but I want to **stop searching after a certain index** for efficiency reasons.

#### Example:

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
string: S  p  a  c  e     -  -  -     t  h  e     f  i  n  a  l     f  r  o  n  t  i  e  r
range:  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  ⬆︎ -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
                                                     max
```

This would mean that I only search the string for a regular expression match **that *starts* before index 15**.

---

The behavior described above is different from searching only a subrange of the string. Here's why:

#### ✅ Should match:

The following example should produce a match at range [5–9], because the match starts before the max index (= 7).

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
string: S  p  a  c  e     -  -  -     t  h  e     f  i  n  a  l     f  r  o  n  t  i  e  r
range:  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  ⬆︎ -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
                             max
```

#### ❎ Should, but would not match:

If I only searched a substring up to the max index (= 7), the regular expression would not be able to match because part of the match would be truncated.

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
string: S  p  a  c  e     -  -  
range:  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  ⬆︎ 
                             max
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: what about `firstMatch` function? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409838-firstmatch

Comment: Prefix your regex with `\A.{0,15}?` or `\A.{0,7}?` or whatever the limit should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a capture group I'm assuming that is the string you are looking for. You can change your expression to this: `^.{0,6}\\s{1,3}(---+)\\s*`. I added the following:

- **^** beginning of string.
- **.{0,6}** to match from zero to six characters.

Changing the expression like this will match what you are looking for, your original expression will match if it starts at most at position **6**, this is your **max**. The difference is that the whole match contains those optional characters, but the first capture group will only contain the dashes you are looking for.

I use the following code at a playground to test the new expression:

```
let regexString = "^.{0,6}\\s{1,3}(---+)\\s*"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString)
let string = "Space --- the final frontier --- these are the voyages of the     
             starship Enterprise. Its continuing mission: to explore strange 
             new worlds. To seek out new life and new civilizations. To boldly   
             go where no one has gone before!"

let matches = regex?.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
if let firstMatch = matches?.first {
    print("Whole regex match starts at index: \(firstMatch.range.lowerBound)")
    print("Whole match: \(String(string[Range(firstMatch.range, in: string)!]))")
    print("Capture group start at index: \(firstMatch.range(at: 1).lowerBound)")
    print("Capture group string: \(String(string[Range(firstMatch.range(at: 1), in: string)!]))")
} else {
    print("No matches")
}
```

Running the code above shows the following results:

> Whole regex match starts at index: 0
>
> Whole match: Space ---
>
> Capture group start at index: 6
>
> Capture group string: ---

If `string` is change like this: `let string = "The space --- the final frontier --- these are the ...` the result is:

> No matches

since the `\\s{1,3}` is starting at index **10**.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Brilliant answer – especially for picking up that string example of mine. ;) Thank you! I wonder why I didn't think of this; I must be out of practice with regex... ;)

Comment: Why isn't this getting more up votes?! I mean A LOT MORE.
I know Mischa already said this but it warrants repeating. This really is brilliant.
Seeing `^.{0,6}` led me to fixing this small regex check I wanted to make but couldn't figure out. Just a fantastic solution! This helped me remove 3 function calls and a variable reassignment in my parser which equals better run time.

Thank you, Aaron!